# Returning the inner portion of an element with Cheerio in Node.js

Tags: node.js, cheerio

Consider the following bit of HTML

```
<div>
    <span>1000</span>Geoffery<span>5</span>
</div>
```

How is it possible using Cheerio to extract `Geoffery`. Currently, if I use

```
$('div').text()
```

I get `1000Geoffery5`.

Answer (score 1):

Since I do not have enough rep to comment, Try

```
$('div').children().eq(0).children().eq(0).text()
```

The `.text()` gives you the text of the elements in the selector. Using `.children.eq(0).children().eq(0)` you select the first child of the first child of the `div` element which holds the required text.

Edit: You can also use `.first()` instead of `.eq(0)`